# Creating a short unique string for each unique long string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hash, md5

I'm trying to create a url shortener system in c# and asp.net mvc. I know about hashtable and I know how to create a redirect system etc. The problem is indexing long urls in database. Some urls may have up to 4000 character length, and it seems it is a bad idea to index this kind of strings. The question is: How can I create a unique short string for each url? for example MD5 can help me? Is MD5 really unique for each string?

NOTE: I see that Gravatar uses MD5 for emails, so if each email address is unique, then its MD5 hashed value is unique. Is it right? Can I use same solution for urls?

Comment: MD5 is 128 bit so it'll probably be unique enough.

Comment: You seek a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) to avoid collisions.

Comment: @HABO Nice article and good solution. Please post your suggestion as an answer, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) is one that guarantees no collisions.  Since your application cannot accomodate hash chains, a perfect hash is the way to go.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Practical perfect hashes are certainly a challenge.  A minimal one all the more so.  Since the OP requested that I repost my comment as an answer, I did so.  It looks like a subject for an advanced degree to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MD5 or SHA1 for such purposes as your described.

Hashes aren't completely unique. As example if you have 4000 bytes array, that's mean that you potentially have 256^4000 combinaton. And MD5 has will have 256^16 combination. So, there is a possibility of collisions. However, for all practical purposes (except cryptography), you don't never to worry about collisions.

If you are interested to real about collission vulnerability of MD5 (related to cryptographical use), you can do it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities)

Answer (score 0):

The hashing approaches already mentioned will work fine for creating unique short strings that will probably uniquely identify your URL's. However, I'd like to propose an alternate approach.

Create a database table with two columns, ID (an integer) and URL (a string). Create a row in the table for each URL you wish to track. Then, refer to each URL by its ID. Make the ID auto-incrementing, this will ensure uniqueness.

This addresses the problem of how to translate from the shortened version to the longer version: simply join on the table in the database. With hashing, this would become a problem because hashing is one-way. The resulting page identifiers will also be shorter than MD5 hashes, and will only contain digits so they will be easy to include in URL query strings, etc.

Comment: thanks. But it seems you didnt read the question compelete. I know about this staffs, my probelem is indexing urls. Index long strings is not good. However thanks again

Comment: Your question isn't clear, because you have not defined what you mean by "indexing". There are many things that you could be referring to. Unless you give more real-world details about what you're trying to do, it's difficult to give you an adequate answer. It seems to me that what you are trying to do will not work at all because you cannot convert hashes back to URL's. It's hard to see what real-world problem your question addresses.

Comment: If your problem is related to building an RDBMS index for URL's that are already in an RDBMS table, then I would suggest you use some RDBMS-specific method like hash indexes.

Comment: If what you are really aiming for is "How do I simulate hash indexes on SQL Server," then the answer is probably to do what you're trying to do, i.e. hash the names yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could try to make from the url string a byte(each char can be a byte) array and then use encoding (Base64 for example, or you can create one yourself if you want to go that far), Then if you want to decode you just use base 64 decoding and make from the bytes (in the array) again chars. However I am not sure or this will be a long string or not, but I am pretty sure it will be unique.

(PS you should ofc apply some logic first like always remove http:// and add it again later when decoding)